# Android Studio 1.5.1 Font Renders Differently Than Other IntelliJ Editors

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I use the Hack font in AndroidStudio, PhpStorm, RubyMine and my terminal.  However, the font renders badly in AndroidStudio compared to the the other editors and the terminal.

AndroidStudio:

[image]

RubyMine:

[image]

Is there a known solution for this?  My searches only show up problems related to old JDK 1.6.  I'm using 1.8.0_65.